# PHP Session Setup

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to use `session` variable across all my `php` pages. I researched and found some helpful information, but I'm having some issues putting it to use. I noticed that when I trying to set the `ini` that I'm getting an error.

```
file: C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Index.php


<?php
 ini_set(session.save_path, 'C:/xampp/session');
?>
```

The error I get on the page is:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant session - assumed 'session' in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Index.php on line 2

Notice: Use of undefined constant save_path - assumed 'save_path' in C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Index.php on line 2
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error at all.

Comment: [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ini-set.php) expects argument #1 to be a string. You are not passing a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the setting name in quotes. Otherwise you are trying to concatenate two constants that do not exist.

```
 ini_set('session.save_path', 'C:/xampp/session');
```

Comment: even better add it to php.ini then you dont have to define it on every page

Comment: @Dagon If they have that option, definitely

Comment: its xampp, i cant imagine he doesn't have that option - would say otherwise if it was a hosted site

Comment: @Dagon I wanted to do that do I couldn't locate the php.ini file and the supposed file brought up a php console window...

Comment: @StephenAdkins `phpinfo()` will tell you which configuration file(s) are in use

Comment: @Dagon Even if it were a hosted site, there's always [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) or `.htaccess`

Comment: I would of guessed xampp has that defined when you installed it - but have never used it

Comment: @Phil some hosts disable that :(

Comment: @Dagon Yikes, really? Seems like a terrible idea

Comment: some shared hosts are well crap

Comment: @StephenAdkins Just accept John's answer if it helped. He could surely use the points ;)

Comment: I know that by changing the php.ini file I don't have to include in every file, but I only need to have session_start() in the root php file and not in every php file as well, correct?

Comment: @Phil waiting on the timer to let me

Comment: well it depends what you mean by "root php file"

Comment: Referring to the index.php file. I use includes mostly until I do redirects, which probably means I need the session_start() in the php files I redirect too. Is that correct?

Comment: needs to be in every file that uses sessions